# What is the source to these hadiths about the virtues of memorizing the Quran?

Tags: quran, hadith, reference-request

AoA.
Having studied in a madrassa some time ago, I've heard the following hadiths about the hifz-e-Qur'an:

1. On the day of judgment, the one who memorizes Qur'an (hafiz) will recite the Qur'an. On each verse, a step (of stairs) will appear before him and he will take the step and go higher. The more he remembers, the higher he goes. The higher he goes, the better darja of jannah he will enter. (i.e. if he remembers whole Qur'an without mistakes, he'll go to jannah al-firdous).
2. On the day of judgment, the one who memorizes Qur'an (hafiz) will have a blank list. He will write names of 10 people in it and those people will be forgiven and entered to jannah without any punishment
3. The one who memorizes Qur'an (hafiz) and then forgets it will be resurrected blind on the day of judgment.
4. The parents of the one who memorizes Qur'an (hafiz) will wear a crown on the day of judgment.

However, I cannot find any reference to these hadiths. Does anybody know if these hadiths are sahih or fabricated? If sahih, can you please give me a link to this hadith on sunnah.com?

Comment: i didnt put this as an answer because im not 100% sure, but i go to a shariah course, and the first hadith you stated has been mentioned before, so i am assuming it is true because the teachers at my college dont say anything unkess they are 100% sure of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I couldn't find that particular wording; most likely you were referring to this one:

> Abu Saed Al-Khudri that the Messenger of Allah said: "It will be
> said to the companion of the Quran, when he enters Paradise: 'Recite
> and rise one degree for ever Verse,' until he recites the last thing
> that he knows."

[(Sunan ibn Majah)](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3780)

This is inauthentic as Atiyah bin Sa'ed was weak (ref.Abu Hatim and Abu Jafar), and he was the only person to report it from Abu Sa'ed.

2. It couldn't be found, but the closest wording are these:

> "Whoever recites the Quran and memorizes it, making lawful what it
> makes lawful, and unlawful what it makes unlawful, Allah will admit
> him to Paradise due to it, and grant him intercession for ten of his
> family members who were to be consigned to the Fire."

([Jami at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/631460))

It's inauthentic because of Hafs bin Sulaiman, who was weak (ref. Abu Zurr) and Kathir bin Zathan was unknown (ref Abu Hatim).

> 'Whoever reads the Quran and memorizes it, Allah will admit him to
> Paradise and allow him to intercede for ten of his family members who
> all deserved to enter Hell.'"

([Sunan ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1252150))

This one is inauthentic due to the person named Kathir mentioned above.

3. There's no hadith like this, but perhaps you're referring to the Quranic ayah:

> "And whoever turns away from My remembrance - indeed, he will have a
> depressed life, and We will gather him on the Day of Resurrection
> blind."

([Surah Taha 20:124](http://quran.com/20/124))

4. Similar hadiths:

> If anyone recites the Quran and acts according to its content, on the
> Day of Judgement his parents will be given to wear a crown whose light
> is better than the light of the sun in the dwellings of this world if
> it were among you. So what do you think of him who acts according to
> this?

([Sunan Abu Dawud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/38))

Yahya bin Ayub, Zaban, and Sahl are all rejected and considered weak.

So none of these hadiths -excluding the Ayah 20:125- are authentic.

Comment: 1) But the link says it's "Hasan"? I'm confused. Also, what does the "companion of the Quran" mean?
3) So it is not about memorizing the Qur'an, rather it is about turning away from Qur'an altogether? So it does not apply to a person who memorizes Qur'an, then forgets it, but still acts according to Qur'an?

Comment: It's definitely an inauthentic hadith, and not Hasan. Ata was declared weak by many early scholars, so there's no mistake in rejecting what he reports.    The words "companion of the Quran" or "sahib al-Quran" means someone who has a closeness to the Quran.  It can apply to someone who reads it and follows.  Just memorizing the Quran isn't enough.  We have to follow it also.

Comment: *Atiyah not Ata.  Atiyah bin Sa'ed was declared weak by Yahya bin Sa'ed, Sufyan aThawri, Ahmed bin Hanbal, an-Nisai, ad-Daraqutni, Abu Hatim arRazi, Abu Jafar alAqili...

Answer (score 0):

Wa'alaikum assalam

4. Hadith about parents wearing crown, this hadith is in Mishkatul Masabeeh, p. 186 on the authority of Musnad Ahmad and the Sunan of Abu Dawood.

> “Whosoever learns the Qur’an and practices upon what’s in it, then on
>   the Day of Judgement his parents will be made to wear a crown which
>   will be more radiant than the sun if it were to be in your home, so
>   what do you think of the person who has practiced upon it?”

3. the hadith about forgetting Quran,it is daeef:

> “The sins of my Ummah were shown to me and there is no sin greater
>   than that of a man who was given or was helped to memorize a Surah or
>   an Ayah of the Qur’an and then he forgot it.”

Explained in detail here: http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/quran-and-hadith/sciences-of-the-quran/175420.html

2. i never came across such hadith, could not even find it anywhere
3. Never heard such hadith as well.